# Firefox addon SDK remove built-in context items

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu, firefox-addon-sdk

Using the restartless extension and Add-on SDK, is it possible to remove Context Menu items that are already built-in?

My goal is to build a plugin for context menu, which observes what items are mostly used and hides the rest into a submenu or something. And thus I would need to somehow remove already existing items from the menu (ie. *View Image, Save Image As*...).

Is it possible?

I'm a starter in FF addon world, so I would appreciate any direction in this matter. Thx.